# Raku/Perl6: How to restrict match method to capture group?

Tags: regex, raku

I am attempting to match three letters from a file name with the 1000Genomes project, and three letters only, from strings like `ethnicity_lists/PEL.txt` I should only get `PEL`.  The rest of the string is irrelevant.

```
my $p1-label = @populations[$p1-index].match(/^ethnicity_lists\/(<[A..Y]>)**3\.txt$/);
```

The problem is that `$p1-label` includes the entire string beyond the capture group.

I have put the parentheses around `<[A..Y]>` to emphasize that I only want that group.

Looking through https://docs.perl6.org/routine/match

I try to be as specific as possible to prevent any possible errors, which is why I include the entire string.

If I do the Perl5-style match:

```
if @populations[$p1-index] ~~ /^ethnicity_lists\/(<[A..Y]>)**3\.txt$/ {
    put $0.join(''); # strange that this outputs an array instead of a string
}
```

I've tried all of the adverbs for the `match` method but none do the necessary job.

How can I restrict a `match` method to only the capture group in the regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Holli's answer makes a key point and @Scimon's digs in deeper about why you got the result you got but...

If you **doubly** emphasize what part you want with `<( ... )>` instead of just `( ... )` it makes just that part become the overall capture object.

And if you use `put` instead of `say` you get the *machine friendly* stringification (same as `.Str`, so in this case `PEL`) instead of the *human friendly* stringification (same as `.gist`, so in this case it would have been `｢PEL｣`):

```
put 'fooPELbar' ~~ / foo  ( ... )  bar /; # fooPELbar
put 'fooPELbar' ~~ / foo <( ... )> bar /; # PEL
```

Comment: Thank you @Holli. :) .oO ( I'm more than hopy )

Comment: Oooooooo. I missed that. Awesome. (I added it to my answer to make it more complete. Hope you don't mind).

Comment: @Scimon Awesome. :)

Answer (score 7):

The match method returns a Match object that comprises all the information about your match. If you do :

```
my $p1-label = @populations[$p1-index].match(/^ethnicity_lists\/(<[A..Y]>)**3\.txt$/);
say $p1-label;
```

You'll see it includes 3 items flagged as `0` because of the mentioned **3 outside the brackets :

```
｢ethnicity_lists/PEL.txt｣
 0 => ｢P｣
 0 => ｢E｣
 0 => ｢L｣
```

Getting the Str representation of the Match object gives you the complete match. But you can also ask for it's `[0]` index.

```
say  say $p1-label[0]'
[｢P｣ ｢E｣ ｢L｣]
```

Lets fix the regular expression to put the quantifier in the brackets and see what we get.

```
my $p1-label = @populations[$p1-index].match(/^ethnicity_lists\/(<[A..Y]>**3)\.txt$/);
say $p1-label;
｢ethnicity_lists/PEL.txt｣
 0 => ｢PEL｣
```

Looking better. Now if you only want the `PEL` bit you've got two options. You can just get the Str representation of the first item in the match :

```
my $p1-label = @populations[$p1-index].match(/^ethnicity_lists\/(<[A..Y]>**3)\.txt$/)[0].Str;
say $p1-label;
PEL
```

Note if I don't coerce it to a String I get the match object of the sub match. (Which can be useful but not what you need).

Or you can use Zero Width assertions and skip the capturing altogether :

```
my $p1-label = @populations[$p1-index].match(/<?after ^ethnicity_lists\/><[A..Y]>**3<?before \.txt$>/).Str;
say $p1-label;
PEL
```

Here we are matching 3 upper case letters that occur *after* the expression `^ethnicity_lists\/` and *before* `\.txt$` but they aren't included in the match itself.

Or as pointed out by @raiph you can use a double capture to tell the system this is the only bit you want :

```
my $p1-label = @populations[$p1-index].match(/^ethnicity_lists\/<(<[A..Y]>**3)>\.txt$/)[0].Str;
say $p1-label;
PEL
```

This last one is probably best.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

It outputs an array because the capturing group matches multiple times. You need to put the quantifier inside the group:

```
/^ethnicity_lists\/(<[A..Y]>**3)\.txt$/;
say $0; # PEL
```